# Join tables by t1.datetime and MAX(t2.datetime)

Tags: sql, join, sql-server-2008-r2, max

I have a problem with joining two tables by a `datetime` column.

I need to join on something like `Table1.datetime>MAX(Table2.datetime)`.
I don't have any other column I could join on. Can you help me?

Example of `Table1` (over 370.000 rows):

```
timestamp                data1  data2  data3
-----------------------  -----  -----  -----
2011-05-09 08:55:19.990  x1     w12    j3
2011-05-09 08:56:19.990  x4     w22    j3
2011-05-09 08:57:19.990  x5     w23    j3
2011-05-09 08:58:19.990  x7     w25    j3
2011-05-09 08:59:19.990  x2     w19    j3
2011-05-09 09:01:19.990  x3     w18    j3
```

Example of `Table2` (over 2.000 rows):

```
timestamp                data8
-----------------------  -----
2011-05-09 07:55:11.990  y1
2011-05-09 07:56:13.990  y9
2011-05-09 08:17:14.990  y3
2011-05-09 08:28:15.990  y8
2011-05-09 08:59:16.990  y5
2011-05-09 09:02:19.990  y6
```

So the data in `Table1` joined with `Table2` should have values:

```
timestamp                data1  data2  data3  timestamp                data8
-----------------------  -----  -----  -----  -----------------------  -----
2011-05-09 08:55:19.990  x1     w12    j3     2011-05-09 08:28:15.990  y8
2011-05-09 08:56:19.990  x4     w22    j3     2011-05-09 08:28:15.990  y8
2011-05-09 08:57:19.990  x5     w23    j3     2011-05-09 08:28:15.990  y8
2011-05-09 08:58:19.990  x7     w25    j3     2011-05-09 08:28:15.990  y8
2011-05-09 08:59:19.990  x2     w19    j3     2011-05-09 08:59:16.990  y5
2011-05-09 09:01:19.990  x3     w18    j3     2011-05-09 08:59:16.990  y5
```

Comment: What database system you're using?

Comment: MS SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 1):

Use option with CROSS [APPLY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) and TOP operators

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Table1 t1 CROSS APPLY (
                                SELECT TOP 1 t2.[TIMESTAMP], t2.data8
                                FROM dbo.Table2 t2
                                WHERE t2.[TIMESTAMP] < t1.[TIMESTAMP]
                                ORDER BY t2.[TIMESTAMP] DESC
                                ) o
```

See demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3dcf8/5)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, you need to join the whole Table2 to every row of Table 1, where Table1.timestamp > Max(Table2.timestamp)? Well, the below query should do the trick, but may be you need to clarify the question.

```
Select * from Table1 t1, Table2 t2
Where t1.timestamp > (select MAX(t3.timestamp) from Table2 t3)
```

Comment: I need whole Table 1 joined with Table2.timestamp and T2.timestamp must be the last timestamp before Table1.timestamp.

So to simplify: 
I've got date from Table1 ex. 2012-05-01 
Table2 has dates 2012-01-01, 2012-02-01,**2012-04-30**,2012-05-05.

Select should join Table1=>Table2 like 2012-05-01=>2012-04-30.
The date 2012-04-30 is the last date before given from Table1.